# How to remove border in PhpWord table?

Tags: php, border, phpword

I has create table using phpword. I want set border for specific cell only. For testing, I have create two array style, `border=6` and `border=0`. I set style1 to cell 1 and style2 to cell 2. In word file generated, both cell has border.

```
<?php
 include_once '../vendor/autoload.php';
use PhpOffice\PhpWord\Element\Table;
use PhpOffice\PhpWord\TemplateProcessor;
use PhpOffice\PhpWord\ComplexType\TblWidth;

$styleCell1 = array('borderColor' =>'black', 'borderSize' => 6)
$styleCell2 = array('borderColor' =>'black', 'borderSize' => 0);
$table = new Table();

    $table->addRow();
    $table->addCell(700,$styleCell1)->addText('cell 1');
    $table->addCell(500,$styleCell2)->addText(cell 2);
 $phpWord = new TemplateProcessor('phpWordTableTemplate.docx');
 $phpWord->setComplexBlock('{table}', $table);
 $phpWord->saveAs('template_with_table_output.docx');
 ?>
```

How to remove border in PhpWord table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can set border none to table cell only:

```
use PhpOffice\PhpWord\SimpleType\Border;
$styleCell2 = array('borderColor'=>'black', 'borderSize'=> 0,  'borderStyle' => Border::NONE);
```